# Parsing Multi-cultural Datetimes

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, internationalization, antlr4

I have a multi-lingual and multi-cultural web application. On all of our list pages we have a search bar which allows us to filter the list. This calls ANTLR4 to parse the filter into our objects. My main issue now is that I am trying to add something to the ANTLR grammar to account for all the differing date time formats. With varied symbols either before or after it is slightly difficult to form the correct fragments. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Here is the current grammar that is made specifically for am/pm formats:

```
DATE_TIME12HR : SINGLE_QUOTE DEF_DATE BLANK DEF_TIME12HR SINGLE_QUOTE;
DATE_TIME24HR : SINGLE_QUOTE DEF_DATE BLANK DEF_TIME24HR SINGLE_QUOTE;
DATE : SINGLE_QUOTE DEF_DATE SINGLE_QUOTE;

fragment DATE_SEPARATOR: (SLASH|PERIOD|DASH|COMMA|BLANK);
fragment TIME_SEPARATOR: (COLON|PERIOD|BLANK|COMMA);
fragment DEF_DATE: [0-9]* DATE_SEPARATOR [0-9]* DATE_SEPARATOR [0-9]*;
fragment DEF_TIME24HR: [0-2][0-9] TIME_SEPARATOR [0-5][0-9] TIME_SEPARATOR [0-5][0-9];
fragment DEF_TIME12HR: [0-1]?[0-9] TIME_SEPARATOR [0-5][0-9] TIME_SEPARATOR [0-5][0-9] [ ]([Aa]|[Pp])[Mm];
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I would rather not have to hard code things for each culture.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to use a control on your web page that allows the user to specify the dates needed, rather than having them type text that needs to be parsed.

Comment: The only problem is that it won't just be accessible through the web. Our REST endpoints also allow for a filter parameter that gets run through ANTLR. In the future that might be our approach because currently we aren't allowing specific filtering for dates from the UI. However, I am just looking to hammer out this globalization for ANTLR now rather than when it is needed down the road. I know ANTLR is used a lot for parsing date times. I am just hoping someone else has ran into this before :)